# I am trying to make a button for a game but it says I am trying to compare a number with a nil

Tags: lua

It says that I am comparing a nil with a number, but I don't think I am. The nil is an input on where the x and/or y values of where I am touching the screen `inputX` and `inputY` but it states they are nil value but they are number values. What is happening?

This is the code:

```
rectX = 1
rectY = 1
rectW = 10
rectH = 10

function onTick()
    isPressed = input.getBool(1)
    inputX = input.getNumber(3)
    inputY = input.getNumber(4)
    output.setBool(1, isPressingRectangle)
end

if inputX <= rectX and inputY <= rectY then 
    isPressingRectangle = true 
else 
    isPressingRectangle = false

    function onDraw()
        if (isPressingRectangle) then 
            screen.drawRectF(1,1,10,10)
        else
            screen.drawRect(1,1,10,10)
    end

    screen.drawText(16,16,inputX)
    screen.drawText(35,16,inputY)
end

end
```

I was trying to make it to were if the `inputX` aka the touch vale on the x axis and the `inputY` aka the touch vale on the y axis was less then or equal to the drawn rectangles x and y values it would draw a filled in rectangle but if it wasn't it wouldn't draw a full rectangle it would draw an outlined one but it says I'm comparing a nil with a number.

Comment: It seems this is within a function... And you are defining more functions inside it. Remember, functions in lua are treated like variables. Your `onTick` function is being declared, and can be executed using `onTick()`, but you are not doing that, so `inputX` and `inputY` probably are `nil`. 

Either, make sure `onTick` is being called by the game engine, in which case it may be in the wrong scope (because it is being declared inside a function, it seems), or you need to give inputX and inputY default values. Probably both :)

Comment: how would i call the ontick?  and what do you mean that functons are being called within another function? like what is the function inside of the function i ak sorry if i seem annoyi g or am being annoying but i am currently in school and my last 2 brain cells are fighting

Comment: rectX=12
rectY=13 
rectW=10
rectH=10
function onTick()
isPressed=input.getBool(1)
inputX=input.getNumber(3)
inputY=input.getNumber(4)
output.setBool(1, isPressingRectangle)
if inputX <= rectX and inputY <= rectY then inRectangle = true 
 else inRectangle = false
end
if isPressed and inRectangle then isPressingRectangle = true
 else isPressingRectangle = false
  end
end
function onDraw()
if (isPressingRectangle) then screen.setColor(0,255,0) screen.drawRectF(1,1,10,10)
 else
  screen.setColor(255,0,0) screen.drawRect(1,1,10,10)
end 

I needed to move one of the ends

Answer (score 0):

It seems @Maxime Franchot and @Rhys Smith have the solution.

Here's your script a bit different:

```
rectX = 1
rectY = 1
rectW = 10
rectH = 10
function onTick()
    isPressed = input.getBool(1)
    inputX = input.getNumber(3)
    inputY = input.getNumber(4)
    output.setBool(1, isPressingRectangle)
end
if inputX <= rectX and inputY <= rectY then
    isPressingRectangle = true
else
    isPressingRectangle = false
    function onDraw()
        if (isPressingRectangle) then
            screen.drawRectF(1,1,10,10)
        else
            screen.drawRect(1,1,10,10)
        end 
        screen.drawText(16,16,inputX)
        screen.drawText(35,16,inputY)
    end
end
```

Please try this instead:

```
rectX = 1
rectY = 1
rectW = 10
rectH = 10
function onTick()
    isPressed = input.getBool(1)
    inputX = input.getNumber(3)
    inputY = input.getNumber(4)
    output.setBool(1, isPressingRectangle)
    if inputX <= rectX and inputY <= rectY then
        isPressingRectangle = true
    else
        isPressingRectangle = false
    end
end
function onDraw()
    if (isPressingRectangle) then
        screen.drawRectF(1,1,10,10)
    else
        screen.drawRect(1,1,10,10)
    end 
    screen.drawText(16,16,inputX)
    screen.drawText(35,16,inputY)
end
```

Also, I don't notice input being declared.  If it is being passed to the function onTick() than you will likely need to declare it by changing the line 'function onTick()' to 'function onTick(input)' and same with 'function onDraw()' to 'function onDraw(screen)'

Comment: its the game system it wasnt the input it was wrongly worded or placed end not seperating functions or a misspell

Comment: Glad you got it working.